# Multiline equation in cases with special symbols

Tags: equations, pdftex, amsmath

```
\begin{equation*}
$\theta$ = 
\begin{cases}
    $\eta$    &     \text{$\widehat{P} \textless \bar{P}$}\\
    $\eta$    &     \text{$\widehat{P} \textgreater \bar{P}$}
\end{cases}
\label{eq: test}
\end{equation*}
```

I am unable to compile that. What is it that I need to add additionally? Am I missing a `$` somewhere?

Comment: The first line should be ``\eta & \widehat{P} < \bar{P}\\`` and similarly for the second line; you're already in math mode inside `cases`.

Comment: I still have compilation warnings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have too many `$` characters! The `cases` environment is in math mode, as well as `equation*`, so you should type

```
\begin{equation*}
\theta = 
\begin{cases}
    \eta    &     \widehat{P} < \bar{P}\\
    \eta    &     \widehat{P} > \bar{P}
\end{cases}
\label{eq: test}
\end{equation*}
```

If you want to add text to the side conditions, you can use `\text`, for instance in

```
\begin{equation*}
\theta = 
\begin{cases}
\eta & \text{if $\widehat{P} < \bar{P}$}\\
\eta & \text{if $\widehat{P} > \bar{P}$}
\end{cases}
\label{eq: test}
\end{equation*}
```

In this case the `$` are necessary for getting back in math mode inside `\text`.

Comment: That is right. Kicked the `$`'s out.. i'm bankrupt..but it compiles!

Comment: The `$` is needed only when you are in text mode for an inline formula. A math display is typeset in math mode, so `$` inside it are wrong (unless they are in the argument to `\text`, but you don't need it).